# Using BufferBlock with throttling option for consumer

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

In my producer-consumer application, I defined a BufferBlock as the queue to add items.

```
 public static BufferBlock<AppointmentReminder> m_Queue = new BufferBlock<AppointmentReminder>();
 SemaphoreSlim seaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(4);
```

Then to add items to the queue, I have

```
    private static void Producer()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            AppointmentReminder reminder = new AppointmentReminder();
            reminder.UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
            reminder.CallMethod = "Number";
            reminder.sString = "1234567890";
            m_Queue.Post(reminder);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        {
            AppointmentReminder reminder = new AppointmentReminder();
            reminder.UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
            reminder.CallMethod = "Letter";
            reminder.sString = "abcdefghij";
            m_Queue.Post(reminder);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            AppointmentReminder reminder = new AppointmentReminder();
            reminder.UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();
            reminder.CallMethod = "Mixed";
            reminder.sString = "abcd12345y";
            m_Queue.Post(reminder);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} items in the queue.\n", m_Queue.Count);
    }
```

Now I have to deal with consumer part. There is a method `RunScript(AppointmentReminder callData)` to do that. It means we need to call the method in the consumer part if an item available. But there is a throttling restriction. The maximum processing items are 4 at any time.

So I have:

```
    private async static Task Consumer()
    {
        try
        {
            while (await m_Queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
            {
                AppointmentReminder reminder = m_Queue.Receive();
                Call d = new Call();
                d.RunScript(reminder);
            }

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NullReferenceException: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And to race producer and consumer,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AliveEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Producer(); 
        var consumer = Consumer();
        consumer.Wait();        
    }
```

My question is that I am not strong on [Task Parallel Library (TPL).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) How to apply the throttling constraint to the consumer?

**Edit: October 03 2014:**

Based on svick's solution. The code for the consumer is:

```
    private async static Task Consumer()
    {
        try
        {
            while (await m_Queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
            {
                var consumerBlock = new ActionBlock<AppointmentReminder>(
remainder => new Call().RunScript(remainder),
new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 });
                m_Queue.LinkTo(
consumerBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
                m_Queue.Complete();
                consumerBlock.Completion.Wait();
            }
            // m_Queue is a static BufferBlock in the original code.
        }
```

Comment: You're getting closer with your edit, but still not quite there. Firstly, `while (await m_Queue.OutputAvailableAsync())` is now completely redundant - you can get rid of it. Secondly, if your consumer is an `async Task`, you might as well `await consumerBlock.Completion` instead of blocking with `Completion.Wait()`. Thirdly, `m_Queue.Complete()` really belongs in the producer (right after all the `Post`s), not in the consumer.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, Can I remove `m_Queue.Complete()`? Because in the real world case, the items will be added in a while loop.Which means keeping add item to the queue forever and never stop.

Comment: you sure can, although in that case you have to be particularly careful: if your producer keeps consistently churning out items faster than the consumer can process them, you've got a problem on your hands. If it does become an issue, I'd be throttling *the producer* as well (easily done with `m_Queue = new BufferBlock<AppointmentReminder>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1000 })` and using `m_Queue.SendAsync<T>(T)` instead of `Post`.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, yes in my application the producer is much faster than the consumer. Another question is can I also remove `consumerBlock.Completion.Wait();`? My application is a telephony application, it runs 365x7x24 and never stops.

Comment: Something somewhere *has* to be throttled. If the consumer can't process the items quickly enough, there's no point queuing them up after a certain point - you're just wasting memory. So yes, you will need bounded capacity and `SendAsync` by the sound of it. In terms of not awaiting consumer completion - you're right: if there's no completion, there isn't much point in awaiting it. Truth is, your `ActionBlock` *is* your consumer, so you can do away with the `Consumer()` method call and just have the `ActionBlock` initialisation and `m_Queue.LinkTo` call in its place.

Comment: You better be handling any and all exceptions inside your `new Call().RunScript` method though, because if it throws, the pipeline will grind to a halt and silently throw - and you may not even know because the `ActionBlock`s "task" will run unobserved. That's the one drawback of *not* observing the pipeline's completion (even if completion never occurs in non-exceptional circumstances), cause if you were, you could log the critical exception, tear down the process, restart the consumer - whatever suits your scenario.

Comment: So do I have to set `Consumer()` as async since the `SendAsync` for the producer? or just let both race naturally, which means both of method are `void`?

Comment: `SendAsync` belongs in the producer, not the consumer. Personally I'd make both producer and consumer async. Producer - because you need to use `SendAsync` in order to take advantage of bounded capacity, consumer - because ideally you'd be awaiting your `ActionBlock`'s completion and catching any exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better option than writing the consumer yourself is to create an [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684), which already supports limiting parallelism:

```
var consumerBlock = new ActionBlock<AppointmentReminder>(
    remainder => new Call().RunScript(remainder),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 });
```

And then link it to the queue:

```
queue.LinkTo(
    consumerBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
```

Finally, wait for it to complete:

```
queue.Complete();
consumerBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

Comment: I want to combine code together. Just edit it, would you please confirm it?

Comment: @Love No, that's wrong. When you use `ActionBlock` like I suggested, you don't need the loop anymore.

Comment: Just a follow up question. It looks like that the code is for parallel problem, can I apply it to concurrent throttling problem as well? Say the maximum concurrent number is 4.